# dynamic directive needs dynamic data

Tags: angularjs, rest

I have a service to collect data via restful slim API.

```
test.factory('DataService', function ($http, $log, $resource) {
    return $resource('php/planets')
});

test.controller('tableviewCtrl', function ($scope, DataService, $resource) {
    DataService.query(function(response) {
        $scope.matches = response;
    });
});
```

and I have a directive:

```
<tableview data="{'view': 'planets', 'settings': {'search': 'false'}, 'cols': ['id','name','region'] }"></tableview>
```

and for example a directive:

```
<tableview data="{'view': 'superheroes', 'settings': {'search': 'false'}, 'cols': ['id','name','strength'] }"></tableview>
```

Depending on the "view" parameter I want change the `$resource` URL in my service. For example from `php/planets` to `php/projects`

Any idea how I can handle this?

**EDIT:**

```
test.factory('DataService', function ($http, $log, $resource) {

    resourceName = 'planets';

    return {
        changeResource: function ( resourceName) {
                resourceName = resourceName;
        },
        data: $resource('php/'+resourceName)
    }

});

test.controller('tableviewCtrl', function ($scope, DataService, $resource) {

    DataService.changeResource('superheroes').then(function () {
        DataService.data.query(function(response) {
            $scope.matches = response;
        });
    });

});
```

can somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

I would use an inner controller for each of the `<tableview>`'s that is initialized using the ngInit directive.

Javascript:

```
test.service('DataService', function ($http, $log, $resource) {
      return {

        resourceName = 'planets';

        changeResource: function (resourceName) {
          this.resourceName = resourceName;
        },

        data: $resource('php/' + resourceName)

      }
});

test.controller('tableviewCtrl', function ($scope, DataService, $resource) {

      // am I still necessary?

});

    test.controller('innerCtrl', function ($scope, DataService, $resource) {

      $scope.init = function(resourceName) {
        DataService.changeResource(resourceName);
        DataService.data.query(function(response) {
          $scope.matches = response;
        });
      };

});
```

HTML:

```
<tableview 
      ng-controller="innerCtrl" 
      ng-init="init('planets')" 
      data="{'view': 'planets', 'settings': {'search': 'false'}, 'cols': ['id','name','region'] }">
</tableview>
```

Comment: How many of those `<tableview>`'s are handled by the controller? One? Many?

Comment: you have a solution for me?

Comment: From the current picture any solution would be only guess after guess until someone solves your problem. Please state more details and parts you already solved.

Comment: i try it...see the startpost please, but i dont have access to the directive scope.data out of the controller, and there is a error with my then() function

Comment: hmm i get an error from >>resourceName = 'planets';<< in the service...unexpected token! what this means? i dont know this init function before...but this seems to be a nice solution, thank you very much!

Comment: when i alert the $scope.init in the controller its undefined? it seemed so that the variable planets isnt passed?